# Вопрос по документации angular > template variables

Tags: angular

Вопрос в следующем, что имеется ввиду в последнем абзаце данного участка документации с оффсайта Angular:

> When you declare the variable on an , the variable refers
> to a TemplateRef instance, which represents the template.
>
> src/app/app.component.html
>
> ```
> <ng-template #ref3></ng-template>
> <button (click)="log(ref3)">Log type of #ref</button>
> ```
>
> In this example, clicking the button calls the log() function, which
> outputs the value of #ref3 to the console. Because the #ref variable
> is on an , the value is TemplateRef.
>
> The following is the expanded browser console output of the
> TemplateRef() function with the name of TemplateRef.
>
> ```
> ▼ ƒ TemplateRef()
> name: "TemplateRef"
> __proto__: Function
> ```

Откуда взялась функция TemplateRef(), когда это по идее класс, что они хотели донести? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит починать про [функции-конструкторы](https://learn.javascript.ru/constructor-new).
В данном случае, при вызове функции создается новый экземпляр класса TemplateRef().

P.S. Функции конструкторы принято называть с большой буквы.